# Use a default sender name when using SendGrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sendgrid

I'm not sure where to set this up at. I'm able to send emails out with my domain (info@domain.com) but I want it to be `Domain info@domain.com` instead of `Info info@domain.com` when users see who sent it. I am using SendGrid, Heroku, Namecheap and Ruby on Rails. How is this done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A "pretty" email address can be specified using a format like

```
"Pretty Name" <uglyname@example.com>
```

Not sure if double- or single-quotes are significant, but assuming they are, your mailer could have the lines

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default :from => '"Pretty Name" <uglyname@example.com>'
   ... rest of mailer code
```